# Play Video From URL By Using Vuforia for Android Native?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to play a video from URL by using the Vuforia Android Native API.

I have changed the code in the VideoPlayback sample, as shown below:

VideoPlayback.java

```
Video from Url
mMovieName[STONES]       = "..Youtube Video link..";
mMovieName[CHIPS]        = "..Youtube Video link..";
mMovieName[celebVM_LOGO] = "..Youtube Video link..";
```

I removed some code from VideoPlayerHelper.java as shown below:

```
for Video from Url, in Load method
AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    afd.close();
```

Added:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
```

And removing the code

```
try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
    afd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "File does not exist");
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
    return false;
}
```

It's not working, can anybody suggest why? Please refer to this link for more information:
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/how-work-video-url-videoplayback

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will only work with links to the actual videos, for example [this one](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4).

Answer (score 0):

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("../video.mp4"); //or any video type
```

Comment: Add some description, and be more explanatory. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks